# Swift 1/2 NSDate get alway Nil on formatting

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, swift2

I don't understand what i'm doing wrong here. I need to format that date but i get always nil, i tried different codes and different format and i guess it's the incorrect format but i don't understand which i need to use, please help me! Thank you very much in advance.

```
var FormatDate: NSDateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
FormatDate.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"

var MyDate: NSDate? = FormatDate.dateFromString("2015-10-07T18:38:26.415Z")
print(MyDate)
```

Comment: your code works fine for me

Comment: Set the formatter's locale to en_US_POSIX.

Comment: it works on Simulator but not on device.

Comment: @rmaddy how do i set that?

Comment: [Searching](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+en_US_POSIX+nsdateformatter) helps.